# Error Stream was not readble

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I wrote the code below and I got an error (Stream was not readble) while execute this line `SR = New StreamReader(FS)` why and how to fix it

the code :

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim FS As FileStream
    Dim SR As StreamReader
    Dim SW As StreamWriter
    Dim FS_Out As FileStream
    FS = New FileStream("C:\Temp\My Picture.JPG", System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate, System.IO.FileAccess.Write)
    SR = New StreamReader(FS)
    FS_Out = New FileStream("C:\Temp\My Picture Out.JPG", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite)
    SW = New StreamWriter(FS_Out)

    Dim alltext As String
    FS.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
    alltext = SR.ReadToEnd()

    'SW.Write (Buffer)



    SR.Close()
    FS.Close()


End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well look at what you've asked for:

```
FS = New FileStream("C:\Temp\My Picture.JPG", _
                    FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write)
```

You've asked to open or create a file for writing. Nothing about reading.

Now, on top of that, you're trying to use `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` for jpeg files. *Don't do that.* Pictures are *binary* files; `TextReader` and `TextWriter` (and the subclasses) are for *text* files. What would the string representation of a picture look like?

Next, you ought to use ["Using" statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to make sure you close your streams/readers/writers even if an exception occurs.

Next, most of the time it's simplest to use the static methods of the [`File`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx) class to open streams or readers for files. That way, the method you use says what you want to do with the stream - e.g. `File.OpenRead`, `File.OpenWrite`, `File.ReadAllText` etc.

Next, if you really want to copy the file, you can use `File.Copy`. If you want to read all the data into memory *and* copy it, you can use `File.ReadAllBytes` and `File.WriteAllBytes` which means you don't need to mess around with the streams yourself at all.

Answer (score 0):

It appear you mismatch the mode on FS, it should be `FileAccess.ReadWrite`.

Answer (score 0):

You open `FS` with only the "write" flag, then try to read from it. Personally I always use `File.OpenRead`, `File.OpenWrite`, etc - much easier *and* clearer.